# button is not clicked using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, eclipse-mars

I am trying to write script for login.. send keys are working 
but the button is not getting clicked.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div style="text-align: right">
    <button id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-wide btn-success col-xs-offset-6"style="width: 85px; font-weight: bold; margin-left: 0px" type="submit"> Sign In</button>
</div>
```

Here is the JAVA code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.By.ByTagName;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;  

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("here is my url");

        driver.findElement(By.id("UserName")).sendKeys("dishashah");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("disha1234");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: are u getting any exception if not  you may try driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN); as well.